# How to pass sublist via intent

Tags: android, list, android-intent, sublist

I am trying to pass the `top50TrendsList` to another activity via `Intent` as shown below in the code, but it is marked with red and I am getting an error message which says:

```
2nd parameter cant be cast to Serializable
```

despite the class `Trend` implements `Serializable` interface.

Please let me know how to pass `top50TrendsList` via `Intent` to another activity? Thanks.

**code**:

```
    List<Trend> top50TrendsList = this.mTrendsList.subList(0, 2);
Collections.sort(this.mTrendsList);
    Intent intentSendBroadcast = new Intent();
    intentSendBroadcast.setAction(ActMain.CONST_BROADCAST_ACTION_ON_LIST_READY);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable(TwitterTrendsAPIService.CONST_BUNDLE_KEY_SERIALIZED_LIST, top50TrendsList);
    intentSendBroadcast.putExtras(b);
    sendBroadcast(intentSendBroadcast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your `Trend` should be `Parcelable`, and then you can do it like

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myArrayList" , top50TrendsList);
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html) to know about `parceable`, and how to make your class `parceable`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the key thing is that List object is being provided, not a Trend

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin oh man, seriously? your list object `top50TrendsList` is of type `Trend`, you should know it

Comment: list object is of type...list

Comment: and he is passing... that list:)

Comment: and List interface does not implement serializable. this answer would be useful if he pass `Trend` object, not a List (notice, not ArrayList) of `Trend` (actually doesn't matter which object exactly) objects

Comment: let me tell you exactly, its a list object which contains objects of `Trend`, and that `Trend` should be parceable or serializeable depending upon the use, i would prefer `parceable`

Comment: `List<Trend> top50TrendsList = this.mTrendsList.subList(0, 2);
b.putSerializable(TwitterTrendsAPIService.CONST_BUNDLE_KEY_SERIALIZED_LIST, top50TrendsList);`
what type is passed here? `List` or `Trend`? so where is the root of compile-time error?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin thats second problem, first problem isto make class `Parceable`, you cannot jump to second problem without solving the first one

Comment: please read carefully: "despite the class Trend implements Serializable interface."

Comment: question is not whether Parcelable is faster than Serializable

Comment: again, have you even checked my answer? `putParcelableArrayListExtra` clearly says that it is expecting `ArrayList` and the person asking the question must have known it by name

Comment: ArrayList, not List :)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList implements Serializable, not List. You are providing an object via List (interface) reference (and Java has single dispatch, so the overloaded method variant to invoke is being identified in compile time by reference type, not actual object type in runtime). Pass it via ArrayList reference and it will be ok for your goals I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parcelable

```
public class Test implements Parcelable
{
    List<String> list;

    protected Test(Parcel in) {
        list = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public Test()
    {}

    public static final Creator<Test> CREATOR = new Creator<Test>() {
        @Override
        public Test createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Test(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Test[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Test[size];
        }
    };

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringList(list);
    }
}
```

setList on Model class and pass to another actiivty:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setList(list);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("list", test);
        startActivity(intent);
```

For getting data from 2nd activity:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("list"))
        {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Test test = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("list");
            list.addAll(test.getList());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Trend class should implements Serializable like this

> public class Trend implements
>   Serializable